# Processing pararelly drainded data from publisher

Tags: java, rx-java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

How to process data pararelly subscribed from `Publisher`?

1. Should I subscribe in a loop in a pool of workers? When I call subscribe in `Project Reactor` I got only one chunk of data. How to "drain all"?
2. How to ensure that every worker will take different chunk of data?

Comment: Please read this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#parallel-processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Project Reactor, use the `parallel()` operator:

```
Flux.from(thePublisher) //if we don't assume publisher is already a Flux
    .parallel() //instruct the Flux to divide work on "rails",
    //but so far these rails are running on the same thread !
    .runOn(Schedulers.parallel()) //now each rail runs on its own thread
    .map(...).etc(...)
    .sequential() //merge the rails back to a single sequence
    //subscribe, or continue processing sequentially
```

RxJava 2 is very similar and has the same `parallel` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Convert each chunk of data into a task and submit it to an `Executor`. Converter may look as follows:

```
class Converter implements Subscriber<T> {
    final Executor executor;
    Subscription subscription;

    Converter(Executor executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        subscription = s;
        s.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(T data) {
        executor.execute(()->process(data));
        subscription.request(1);
    }
    ...        
    void process(T o) {
        ...
    }
}
```